# Why I get "Invalid certificate" error when I use school network?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Why I get "Invalid certificate" error when I use school network? This error usually appears on sites about programming, Linux and about security, privacy or anonymity.

[image]

Sometimes I receive error "Connection refused" when I try access to these websites. Am I victim of Man-In-The-Middle attack?

Comment: We don't have enough information to tell what's going on. One possible scenario is that your school in doing a MitM, other possible scenario is that you actually tried to enter a site while it's certificate was expired or revoked. Even another scenario is that the computer you use in the school network does not trust the CA that issued the certificate. To clarify you should view the page certificate and manually check it

Comment: It occurs on random pages.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify instead of replying in comments. Also, the text from the picture would be more helpful than the picture.

Comment: Please do not screenshot your entire desktop when all you need is a single window's content

Comment: You need to collect and show at least some indicative information, e.g cert subject info,  netstat trace. It will be more conclusive if you learn to capture the traffics using Pcap /wireshark and extract data to analyze them.

Answer (score 1):

You are not victim of an attack, it's because your school employs a SSL Proxy.

In this kind of proxy, every connection (even SSL) is terminated at the proxy, inspected for malware, and if all is fine, re-encrypted with its own certificate and sent to your computer. Usually, the proxy have a certificate authority installed and can create certificates for every single site you access, and this authority is configured as trusted on all computers of the organization.

In your school, they didn't added the certification authority certificate as trusted on the computer you are using.

Comment: What you described is a man in the middle attack. Especially if it is not disclosed to the students.

Comment: This is exactly a Man-in-the-Middle attack, whether you trust the entity performing the attack doesn't make it different

Comment: It is not an attack IF this is the expected way the network works (and it is). Unless you consider an attack when your antivirus intercept a malicious program you downloaded and deletes it.

Comment: You're assuming they're running a proxy. While you may be correct, I would modify this to reflect "Your school MAY be running an SSL proxy consult with faculty." Otherwise someone else may take this as the holy grail and run with it whenever they get the error. As for your secondary comment, make little sense. (AV/interception... Irrelevant)

Comment: @ThoriumBR If the user does not expect this behavior it's not "the expected way the network works". Even in the case that it was clarified and expected that the proxy makes a new certificate for each page I wouldn't call "expected" that the new CA is not trusted by the computers within the organization. Browser warnings shouldn't be discarded without a good reason, and just SUPPOSING that there is a SSL proxy without actual proof of who owns the signing CA is not good enough

Comment: "The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.2" (RFC 5246) clearly states "The TLS protocol provides communications security over the Internet" These TLS Interceptions devices are "Man-In-The-Middle" devices and have serious Security, Privacy and Trust issues.

Comment: An attack is something executed by someone without proper authorization. The network manager of his school has authorization. Every single enterprise proxy works this way. Unless you all consider Juniper, Cisco, Fortinet, Checkpoint and Riverbed attacking entitites. Is a MItM, sure, but is not an attack, and is the expected behavior of a misconfigured CA. His sysadmin should be warned to proper configure the endpoints.